# How to register a inherited Generic Repository in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a generic repository which is inherited from `IDapperDbContext`. How can I register generic repository in `Startup.cs`?

This is the code:

DapperDbContext:

```
public abstract class DapperDbContext : IDapperDbContext
{
    protected readonly IDbConnection InnerConnection;
    private DatabaseSettings dbSettings;

    protected DapperDbContext()
    {
        var dbOptions = Options.Create(new DatabaseSettings());
        InnerConnection = new SqlConnection(dbOptions.Value.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Generic repository interface

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    Task<int> InsertAsync(T model);
}
```

Generic repository implementation

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : DapperDbContext, IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly string _tableName;

    public BaseRepository(string tableName) : base()
    {
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    public async Task<int> InsertAsync(T t)
    {
        var insertQuery = GenerateInsertQuery();

        using (var scope = BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (Connection)
            {
                return await Connection.ExecuteAsync(insertQuery, t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My student repository

```
public class StudentRepository: BaseRepository<Student>,IStudentRepository
{
    public StudentRepository(string tableName):base(tableName)
    {
    }
}
```

How can I register these services in `Startup.cs` and inject them into my controller as follows?

```
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    private StudentRepository _studentRepository;

    public StudentController(StudentRepository repository)
    {
        _studentRepository = repository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateStudent(Student student)
    {
        await _studentRepository.InsertAsync(student);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register them like this:

```
//Generic interface and implementation.
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>),typeof(Repository<>));

services.AddScoped<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>();
```

Comment: I tried this before and not worked. getting exception `Cannot instantiate implementation type 'eSchool.api.Domain.Repository.Repository`1[T]' for service type 'eSchool.api.Domain.Interfaces.IRepository`1[T]'.'` in `program.cs` file in `CreateHostBuilder` method. and FYI, i need to initialize `Repository.cs` with tableName as parameter @bolkay

Comment: Possibly the `abstract` flag.

Comment: Yes. that part worked. but how achive second part. ie, register StudentRepository with table name as a parameter? @bolkay